# Trying to embed a KML layer into my current coding, would it work using Wamp

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have so far created a template of what i want and have manged to start getting each area to work, still got some work to do but I am currently trying to embed a KML file as a layer for my google map.
Here is my full coding below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    

var markers = [];

function createMarker(latlng, html, map, refnum) {
var latlngtxt = (latlng.lat() + ',' + latlng.lng()).split(',');
$.each(latlngtxt, function(i, v){
 v = Math.round(v);
   v += v > 0? (i? 'E' : 'N') : (i? 'W' : 'S');
 latlngtxt[i] = v.replace(/^-/, '');
});
  latlngtxt = latlngtxt.join(', ');
 var ref = $.trim($('#reference').val());
//ref = ref? ref + '<br>' : '';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: ref || html //+ '#' + (markers.length + 1) + '<br>' + html + '<br>' + latlngtxt
  });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: latlng,
html: html,
infowindow: infowindow
 });
 marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
infowindow.open(map, this);
$('#supplementwindow').html(infowindow.content).fadeIn();
 });
 marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
infowindow.close();
$('#supplementwindow').fadeOut();
 });
 markers.push(marker);
 }


var up206b = {};


var map;

function trace(message) {
 if (typeof console != 'undefined') {
console.log(message);
}
}

up206b.initialize = function() {
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.136436, -0.460739);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };


 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 up206b.geocode();
 }


var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'file:///C|/wamp/www/maps/UK County border lines.kml',
map: map
});



var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  up206b.geocode = function() {
 /* for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  markers[i].setMap(null);
}
markers = []; */
var addresses = [$('#address').val(), $('#address2').val()];

addresses.forEach(function(address, refnum) {
if (address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, address, map, refnum);
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
  }
 });
}
jQuery(function($){
$('#removemarker').click(function(){
    var tm = $('#themarkers'), si = tm.get(0).options.selectedIndex, $o = $('option', tm).eq(si), i = $o.val();
    if(!i){return;}
    $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
        if(v.html === i){
            v.setMap(null);
            markers.splice(idx, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $o.remove();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    if(markers.length){
        $.each(markers, function(i, v){
            bounds.extend(v.position);
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    if(markers.length < 2){
        map.setZoom(markers.length? 13 : 8);
    }
});
$('#themarkers').change(function(){
    this.title = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].title;
    var i = this.value;
    if(!i){return;}
    $.each(markers, function(idx, v){
        if(v.html === i){
            map.setCenter(v.position);
            map.setZoom(10);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
$('#showall').click(function(){
    $('#themarkers').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    if(!markers.length){
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(52.136436, -0.460739));
        map.setZoom(13);
        return;
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    if(markers.length === 1){
        map.setZoom(13);
    }
});
  });




  </script>   
 </head>
   <body onload="up206b.initialize()"> 

 <div style="width:300px; height: 500px; float:right; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin: 50px 90px 50px 75px"> 
  <h1 align="center">Map Search</h1>   

  <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; padding:10px;" align="center" >


   <form >
    <br>
    Location 1 <input type="text" id="address">
    <br>
    <br>
    Location 2 
    <input type="text" id="address2">
    <br>
    <br>
    Reference&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="reference">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="up206b.geocode()">
  </form>
  </div>

<div id="menu" style=" position: absolute; margin: 45px 89px;" >
 <select id="Counties">
    <option value="">Select County</option>
      <option value="bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
    <option value="buckinghamshire">Buckinghamshire</option>
    <option value="cambridgeshire">Cambridgeshire</option>                       
    <option value="hertfordshire">Hertfordshire</option>
    <option value="northamptonshire">Northamptonshire</option>
</select>
</div>

</div> 


<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; float:right; margin:20px 75px;"></div>

<div id="supplementwindow" style="border:1px solid #ccc; background:#e5e5e5; align-content:center; float:left; position:absolute; margin:200px 0px 200px 200px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 12px;" >
<input type="button" value="Assign">

</div>


<div id="menu2" style="position: absolute; right: 200px; top: 450px; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 5px;
border-radius: 12px;"><select id="themarkers"><option value="">Select Marker</option>
                       </select><br> 
                       <input type="button" id="showall" title="Or Reset if None" value="Show All"><br>
                       <input type="button" id="removemarker" value="Remove Marker"></div>



</body>  
</html>
```

The snippet of my code below is where I am trying to embed the KML file as a layer. I have tried using an online server URL with my KML and it doesn't work and also using Wamp as a local host server. Would it actually work with Wamp?
Have I placed to coding in the wrong place, have I written it wrong or missed out something? If anyone could give me some guidance, I would appreciate it thanks.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'file:///C|/wamp/www/maps/UK County border lines.kml',
map: map
});
```

Comment: What is the KmlStatus returned by the KmlLayer?

Comment: I don't seem to get anything. Ithe map and markers work when load in the browser just no over lay from the KML file

Comment: What is the [KmlLayerStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerStatus)? I suspect by the name of your KML, it is `DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE` (or `DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND` if you are using a local file that the servers can't access, like `file:///C|/wamp/www/maps/UK County border lines.kml`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview), the KmlLayer URL must be publicly accessible.

> **Overview**
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API supports the KML and GeoRSS data formats for displaying geographic information. These data formats are displayed on a map using a KmlLayer object, whose constructor takes **the URL of a publicly accessible KML** or GeoRSS file.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tdj6cgsg/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    map: map,
    url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/final_map_original_wales1c.xml"
  })
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "KmlStatus=" + kmlLayer.getStatus();
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Like i said in my post I have tried it using a online server (public) aswell but still didn't work hence why I have posted for help. Why are you so quick to mark me down!?

Comment: Where is the online version?

Comment: I get `INVALID_DOCUMENT` for [KmlStatus with that URL.](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tdj6cgsg/2/)

Comment: i believe the kml file is not supported by the google api, so I will have to find another way. Unless you know how I can but all the Coordinates in that KML file into a javascript file to do a dorderline overlay?

Comment: [That particular URL is not valid, valid KML works](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tdj6cgsg/)